Is there a way to fix the error 'Error: Unable to initialize main class code_editor'?
My code Java for this program:
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*;
import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextScrollPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class code_editor {
    private static RSyntaxTextArea textArea;
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static boolean isModified = false;
    private static File currentFile = null;

    private static void openFile() {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                textArea.read(br, null);
                br.close();
                textArea.requestFocus();
                frame.setTitle(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                isModified = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void saveFile() {
        if (currentFile == null) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnValue = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                currentFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile(); // Lưu file hiện tại
            } else {
                return; // Người dùng đã hủy việc lưu file
            }
        }
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(currentFile)) {
            textArea.write(writer);
            frame.setTitle(currentFile.getName());
            isModified = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

    private static void newFile() {
        textArea.setText("");
        frame.setTitle("New File");
        isModified = false;
        currentFile = null;
    }

    public static int __init__() {
        frame = new JFrame("Java IDLE preclassic 100283928");
        textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
        textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle("text/java");
        RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
        frame.add(sp);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                if (isModified) {
                    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                            "Bạn có muốn lưu thay đổi không?",
                            "Xác nhận",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        saveFile();
                    } else if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
                    } else {
                        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
                    }
                } else {
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
                }
            }
        });
        textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                markAsModified();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                markAsModified();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                markAsModified();
            }

            private void markAsModified() {
                if (!frame.getTitle().startsWith("*")) {
                    frame.setTitle("*" + frame.getTitle());
                }
                isModified = true;
            }
        });

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        newMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('N', Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
        openMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('O', Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
        saveMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('S', Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newFile();
            }
        });

        openMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openFile();
            }
        });

        saveMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveFile();
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
        fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        __init__();
    }
}

When I run this program at the file .jar by CMD (command: java -jar java_idle.jar) it show this error:
Error: Unable to initialize main class code_editor
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fife/ui/rtextarea/RTextArea

I'm trying to solve this problem by copy the rsyntaxtextarea.jar to my "lib" folder and using this command: jar cvfe java_idle.jar code_editor . and run my .jar file: java_idle.jar, with this command: java -jar java_idle.jar. I don't know why is not run as i need.
I'm have some question for that:

I can fix this error without using Maven/Gradle?
I can fix this error manually?
Additional information:


IDE: IntelliJ IDEA
OS: Windows 10
Java: 21.0.2


...and run my .jar file: java_idle.jar, with this command: java -jar The only way you're going to be able to do that with any certainty without a build tool is to include the classpath to that dependent jar in the manifest. You need to ship both jars

Also, you need to watch your naming. Class names begin upper case, are in camel case with no underscore. Also avoid using static

You could of course include all the source of the editor pane along with yours for compilation, provided of course that you don't infringe the licence

FYI, a 'fat jar' of your code and theirs weighs in at c. 1.3MB

This is the clue:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fife/ui/rtextarea/RTextArea
Java can't find the org.fife.* classes.  So you need to either include them in your jar or specify them on the classpath.
Coding style recommends that you rename the class to CodeEditor.
